# Tensorflow my GPU is not recognized and There are many dll errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I'm too new with tensorflow and keras, actually I'm trying first to install it correctly. I used Anaconda to make it easier. My question is probabily related to the installation but there might be some erros in script too. Therefore, above, are all steps I made to install tensorflow on anaconda:

#1 - Install with Anaconda prompt as admin

`conda create -n tf_gpu python==3.8`
`conda activate tf_gpu`

`conda install cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1 -c=conda-forge`

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.6.0`

#2 - test integration

`python`
`import tensorflow as tf`
`print(tf.__version__)`
`tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

Test results: I don't know Why none GPU are associated even installing everything, I don't know if the problem is related to this ... (I have a geforce-940mx) ?

Revelant parts of stackTrace:

Many dll erros appeared (dlerror), maybe it's because something wrong with installation:

```
cufft64_10.dll  not found
cublas64_11.dll  not found
curand64_10.dll   not found
...
```

#Conclusion

I need help from you guys. I tried many aways to install tensorflow correctly I'm getting headache, everyone said to install it using a new enviroment in anaconda, the steps looks easy, but many issues are happening, why?

#Aditional information

Tested scripts using VsCode

I have Windowns 10

I tried with more than one version using this link: [GPU tf installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to have **GPU support** in your system.

1. Download the right `NVIDIA driver` as per your product type `(Geforce-940mx)`
2. Download and install `cuDNN, CUDA, CUPTI` according to installed Tensorflow version in your system. You can check [test build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) here.
3. Set the path`(%PATH%)` for each of these in environment variable of your system

**For reference**,

The detailed instruction steps (with all required links to download NVIDIA driver, CUDA, cuDNN, CUPTI) are mentioned in this [Windows setup](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) link to enable **GPU support** in your system.

Then create a new virtual environment using Anaconda command prompt

```
conda create -n tf_gpu1 python==3.8 
conda activate tf_gpu1
```

Install tensorlfow in this (tf_gpu1) virtual environment

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Now, check with the below command if tensorflow is able to access the GPU in your system. You can follow the `test inegration` steps mentioned by you.

```
python
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__      # This code will show the installed tensorflow version
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')   # This will show output in boolean value 'True' or 'False'
```